# How to edit user activation mail body in Joomla 2.5?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

i am using Joomla 2.5 user registration form .After successful registration user will get Activation link throw their registered mail id . I want to Add some content to email body(Footer). i have tried a lot but not succeeded.

Code : registration.php

```
if ($useractivation == 2)
    {
        // Set the link to confirm the user email.
        $uri = JURI::getInstance();
        $base = $uri->toString(array('scheme', 'user', 'pass', 'host', 'port'));
        $data['activate'] = $base.JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&task=registration.activate&token='.$data['activation'], false);

        $emailSubject   = JText::sprintf(
            'COM_USERS_EMAIL_ACCOUNT_DETAILS',
            $data['name'],
            $data['sitename']
        );

        if ($sendpassword)
        {
            $emailBody = JText::sprintf(
                'COM_USERS_EMAIL_REGISTERED_WITH_ADMIN_ACTIVATION_BODY',
                $data['name'],
                $data['sitename'],
                $data['siteurl'].'index.php?option=com_users&task=registration.activate&token='.$data['activation'],
                $data['siteurl'],
                $data['username'],
                $data['password_clear']
            );
        }
        else
        {    $footer1 = "regarts: neuroturma ";
            $emailBody = JText::sprintf(
                'COM_USERS_EMAIL_REGISTERED_WITH_ADMIN_ACTIVATION_BODY_NOPW',
                $data['name'],
                $data['sitename'],
                $data['siteurl'].'index.php?option=com_users&task=registration.activate&token='.$data['activation'],
                $data['siteurl'],
                $data['username'],
                $footer1,//not works
                'regarts: neuroturma'//not works
            );
        }
    }
    elseif ($useractivation == 1)
    {
        // Set the link to activate the user account.
        $uri = JURI::getInstance();
        $base = $uri->toString(array('scheme', 'user', 'pass', 'host', 'port'));
        $data['activate'] = $base.JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&task=registration.activate&token='.$data['activation'], false);

        $emailSubject   = JText::sprintf(
            'COM_USERS_EMAIL_ACCOUNT_DETAILS',
            $data['name'],
            $data['sitename']
        );

        if ($sendpassword)
        {
            $emailBody = JText::sprintf(
                'COM_USERS_EMAIL_REGISTERED_WITH_ACTIVATION_BODY',
                $data['name'],
                $data['sitename'],
                $data['siteurl'].'index.php?option=com_users&task=registration.activate&token='.$data['activation'],
                $data['siteurl'],
                $data['username'],
                $data['password_clear']
            );
        }
        else
        {
            $emailBody = JText::sprintf(
                'COM_USERS_EMAIL_REGISTERED_WITH_ACTIVATION_BODY_NOPW',
                $data['name'],
                $data['sitename'],
                $data['siteurl'].'index.php?option=com_users&task=registration.activate&token='.$data['activation'],
                $data['siteurl'],
                $data['username']
            );
        }
    }
    else
    {

        $emailSubject   = JText::sprintf(
            'COM_USERS_EMAIL_ACCOUNT_DETAILS',
            $data['name'],
            $data['sitename']
        );

        $emailBody = JText::sprintf(
            'COM_USERS_EMAIL_REGISTERED_BODY',
            $data['name'],
            $data['sitename'],
            $data['siteurl']
        );
    }

    // Send the registration email.
    $return = JFactory::getMailer()->sendMail($data['mailfrom'], $data['fromname'], $data['email'], $emailSubject, $emailBody);
```

Where Should i Add my footer content ? Please help me.

Comment: Please ask your question over at [Joomla Stack Exchange](http://joomla.stackexchange.com) ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try editing
/language/en-GB/en-GB.com_user.ini

This links can also help a lot
http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=706&t=871489
http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=624&t=852596